# How can I get the belongsTo of an associated model in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a model called Collection that hasMany CollectionItem. CollectonItem hasOne Listing.

So basically, Collection -> CollectionItem -> Listing.

When I do a find on the Collection, I get the associated CollectionItem. However, how can I get the Listing attached to the CollectionItem?

Essentially, how can I go one level deeper? I have tried setting recursive on Collection to 2 but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Collection hasMany CollectionItem
- Collectionitem hasOne Listing
- Collection actsAs Containable
- CollectionItem actsAs Containable
- Listing actsAs Containable

Simplified version

```
$this->Collection->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(), # your conditions
    'contain' => array(
        'CollectionItem',
        'CollectionItem.Listing',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2):

The much better solution is to use [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the recursive to level 3.